# flex itemの中の文字をitemの幅に合わせて折り返すにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

Tags: css

flex itemの中の文字をitemの幅に合わせて折り返すにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

だとうまくいきません。

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 3px;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><a href="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/" >https://www.yahoo.co.jp/</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/" >https://www.yahoo.co.jp/</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/" >https://www.yahoo.co.jp/</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/" >https://www.yahoo.co.jp/</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/" >https://www.yahoo.co.jp/</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/" >https://www.yahoo.co.jp/</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/" >https://www.yahoo.co.jp/</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/" >https://www.yahoo.co.jp/</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/" >https://www.yahoo.co.jp/</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/" >https://www.yahoo.co.jp/</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/" >https://www.yahoo.co.jp/</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/" >https://www.yahoo.co.jp/</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/" >https://www.yahoo.co.jp/</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/" >https://www.yahoo.co.jp/</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/" >https://www.yahoo.co.jp/</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/" >https://www.yahoo.co.jp/</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/" >https://www.yahoo.co.jp/</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/" >https://www.yahoo.co.jp/</a></div>
</div>
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

青い四角：flex container
リンク：flex item

となっています。

Comment: 恐らく現状こうなっているであろうと予測されるサンプルコードを質問に追記しましたので、異なる箇所などあったら適宜質問のコードを編集してください。

Comment: 私が質問に追記したサンプルコードの場合、 `.item a { width: 100%; word-wrap: break-word; }` でリンクの文字列が折り返される気がしますが、現状のコードと本当に期待している見た目が当初の質問からは読み取れませんので、これが回答になっているのか分かりません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

親要素を

```
display:grid
```

とするとできました！

ありがとうございました！